# Transform arrays and reverse

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here I have a code that will transform me array on X and Y format:

So my code:

```
var tacke = response.routes[0].overview_path,
    newTacke = [[]];
for(var i = 0, len = overviewPath.length; i < len; i++) {
    newTacke[0].push({
       X: tacke[i].lat(),
       Y: tacke[i].lng()
    });
}
```

will transform array `tacke` into newArray `newTacke` from format:

```
TACKE format

[
  [56.789, 12.34],
  [123.45, 87.65]
]
```

to format:

```
newTACKE format

[
  [
    {
      X: 12.34
      Y: 56.789
    },
    {
      X: 87.65,
      Y: 123.45
    }
  ]
]
```

So now I need an solution to tranform if I have `newTacke` into old format like `tacke`

So I did it to tranform `var tacke = response.routes[0].overview_path,` into new format,

Now I need to back it in `tacke` format so to be like this:

```
  [
          [56.789, 12.34],
          [123.45, 87.65]
        ]
```

Is there any way to do that?

So now just `newTacke` to make back in `tacke` array format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as if you can just access first member of `newTacke`, getting an array. Then you iterate that array getting the various couples:

```
// pseudo code

oldTacke = []
for pair in newTacke[0]   # we iterate on [{X Y} {X Y} {X Y}]:
    # pair is now { X Y }
    oldTacke.append([ pair.X, pair.Y ])
```

Answer (score 2):

this will make an JsonArray from a class that named Points for all of it's properties

```
Potints= function (x,y){
this.X=x;
this.Y=y;
this.MakeJson=function() {
return JSON.stringify(this);
}
}
var JsonArry=new Array();
for(var i = 0, len = overviewPath.length; i < len; i++) {
  ObjPoints=new Potints(tacke[i].lat(),tacke[i].lng());
  JsonArry.push(ObjPoints.MakeJson());
    });
}
```

Comment: u may need to change x,X to another names , because idont know javascript is CASESENSITIVE or Not  :D

Answer (score 2):

given the newTackle format:

```
 newTackle = [
  [
    {
      X: 12.34,
      Y: 56.789
    },
    {
      X: 87.65,
      Y: 123.45
    }
  ]
];
```

you can get back to the old format this way:

```
tackle  = newTackle[0].map(function(k){
    return [k.Y, k.X];
});
```

and the result:

```
 console.log(tackle)
 // [
 //        [56.789, 12.34],
 //        [123.45, 87.65]
 // ]
```

Comment: +1: that's actually cleaner and likely faster than my original idea. @DrCode, you'd do well to accept this answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

your question is confusing to me..  anyways..  if your newTacke is like the below format.. this will work..

```
newTacke =  [[{X: 12.34, Y: 56.789 }, {X: 87.65, Y: 123.45 }]] ;

oldTacke = [] ;

newTacke.forEach(function (el,i,arr) {
  oldTacke.push([el[0].X, el[0].Y] , [el[1].X, el[1].Y] ) ;
});
console.log(oldTacke); // [[12.34, 56.789], [87.65, 123.45]]
```

if this is not what you expect..please clarify your answer..